# Cypress running npm and npx scripts in one script sequentially

Tags: npm, cypress, npx

I am using Cypress and I have the following scripts:

```
"merge:reports": "mochawesome-merge mochawesome-report/*.json > cypress-combined-report.json",
"create:html:report": "npm run merge:reports && marge --reportDir final-report cypress-combined-report.json",
"delete:reportFolder": "if exist mochawesome-report rmdir /Q /S mochawesome-report && if exist final-report rmdir /Q /S final-report",
"start": "npm run delete:reportFolder && npx cypress run --browser chrome && npm run merge:reports && `enter code here`npm run create:html:report"
```

What I want is all those scripts running sequentially but I think there is something I am missing here as I am not that familiar with npm and npx as when I trigger this script only it is passing:

```
npx cypress run --browser chrome
```

But when I try to execute the script with all the 4 scripts I am getting an error which I think is due to having a npx script:

```
npm run start
```

Would be glad for any suggestions or advices where I am wrong, thanks!

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: Npm-cache logs:

verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If it is unintentional I could see `enter code here` written for start, please remove that and try running afterwards.
2. Delete the `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` files. Then run `npm i` to install all the dependencies again and then again try running `npm run start`
3. Or Remove npx from the cypress run:
   `"start": "npm run delete:reportFolder && cypress run --browser chrome && npm run merge:reports && npm run create:html:report"`

Comment: Yes this was unintentional while pasting the code.
Tried deleting the node_modules folder and package-lock.json file then running npm i and running npm run start but script fails right after the tests run(right after second script in start).

Comment: How about you use npm instead of npx ?

Comment: npm cypress run --browser chrome doesn't seem to work for me if there is any other alternative to it with options as browser available

Comment: Remove npx from the cypress run command, just write `cypress run --browser chrome`

Comment: Triggers the tests successfully but still after they run it fails before the merge:reports script.

Comment: When you are running cypress run is any of your tests failing ?? Because you are using `&&` so the current command will only run if your previous command is successful.

Comment: Yes I am intentionally having failing tests because I want to test out that I am adding screenshot successfully to my mochawesome report. Can this be ignored somehow?

Comment: You can try adding the `||` operator if you want to run the next command irrespective of whether it passes or fails. But I think this goes beyond the scope of this question. I think you reached a solution for this question, you can always create a new one.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot, think I will leave the start script as it is and add a second script for the report generation on whether it is passing or not like: start | | generateReport. Think this should work.